# ownCloud WebDAV interface seems to be broken

Tags: sync, php, windows-server-2012, webdav, owncloud

I've been trying to host ownCloud on my server but everytime I try to it tells me this :

> Your web server is not yet properly setup to allow files synchronization because the WebDAV interface seems to be broken.
>
> Please double check the installation guides.

This is my setup :

```
Windows Server 2012 R2
IIS 8.5
PHP 5.5.11
ownCloud 6.0.3
MySQL 5.6.17
```

I tried google the error but I can't seem to find anything useful.

Some say I should try if this works :

```
[hostname]/remote.php/webdav/
```

and yes I can navigate to this folder and I can open files from there.

The calendar works and I can also just upload files the web version of ownCloud the only thing that doesn't seem to work is the sync client.

The sync client doesn't say anything it just doesn't connect (Screenshot : http://prntscr.com/3p2apz)

This is the error log :

```
Warning     core    isWebDAVWorking: NO - Reason: [CURL] Error while making request: Could not resolve host: cloud.mcsoftworks.net (error code: 6) (Sabre_DAV_Exception)    2014-06-02T19:56:00+00:00
Warning     core    isWebDAVWorking: NO - Reason: [CURL] Error while making request: Could not resolve host: cloud.mcsoftworks.net (error code: 6) (Sabre_DAV_Exception)    2014-06-02T19:55:47+00:00
Warning     core    isWebDAVWorking: NO - Reason: [CURL] Error while making request: Could not resolve host: cloud.mcsoftworks.net (error code: 6) (Sabre_DAV_Exception)    2014-06-02T19:55:34+00:00
Warning core    isWebDAVWorking: NO - Reason: [CURL] Error while making request: Could not resolve host: cloud.mcsoftworks.net (error code: 6) (Sabre_DAV_Exception)    2014-06-02T19:55:34+00:00
Fatal   webdav  Sabre_DAV_Exception_Forbidden: Path does not exist, or escaping from the base path was detected 2014-06-02T19:54:37+00:00
Fatal   webdav  Sabre_DAV_Exception_Forbidden: Path does not exist, or escaping from the base path was detected 2014-06-02T19:54:36+00:00
Fatal   webdav  Sabre_DAV_Exception_Forbidden: Path does not exist, or escaping from the base path was detected 2014-06-02T19:54:36+00:00
Fatal   webdav  Sabre_DAV_Exception_Forbidden: Path does not exist, or escaping from the base path was detected 2014-06-02T19:54:36+00:00
Warning core    isWebDAVWorking: NO - Reason: [CURL] Error while making request: Could not resolve host: cloud.mcsoftworks.net (error code: 6) (Sabre_DAV_Exception)    2014-06-02T19:51:24+00:00
```

This is my php.ini : http://pastebin.com/es3MB8Uh

Does anyone have any idea on how I should get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disabling WebDAV in IIS? It's not a permanent fix but everything syncs and the desktop app works well, too. Let me know if this helps.